# Por que análise, e não revisão?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, internacionalização

O termo "review", na barra do topo foi traduzido como análise. O termo "revisão" não seria mais adequado? Parece ser [um termo válido](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/revis%C3%A3o) em Portugal também.

Answer (score 11):

Actualmente, e para efeitos de verificação do que é mais comum aqui no site, fiz uma pesquisa por análise e uma por revisão:

- Análise: [37 resultados](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=an%C3%A1lise)

  Grande parte dos resultados são assuntos que mencionam a área já existente rotulada de "Análise".
- Revisão: [22 resultados](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=revis%C3%A3o)

  Grande parte dos resultados são assuntos que falam sobre problemas nos quais os utilizadores aplicaram a palavra "Revisão" ao invés da palavra "Análise".

A palavra "revisão" mediante a minha análise parece mais comummente utilizada para o caso de efectuar a verificação de algo com o intuito de aprovar, rejeitar ou alterar, ao passo que a palavra análise está a ser muito utilizada porque existe uma área do site chamada "análise".

---

## [Análise](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/an%C3%A1lise)

> **a·ná·li·se**
>   (francês analyse)
>   substantivo feminino
>
> 1. Exame minucioso de uma coisa em cada uma das suas partes.
> 2. Separação dos princípios componentes de um corpo ou substância.
> 3. [Figurado]  Exame que se faz de uma produção intelectual. = CRÍTICA, ESTUDO
> 4. [Matemática]  Parte da matemática que estuda os conceitos de continuidade, convergência e limite.
> 5. [Filosofia]  Método de exame pelo qual se sobe das consequências ou efeitos aos princípios ou causas.
> 6. [Medicina]  Exame laboratorial com fins diagnósticos, feito em amostras de substâncias ou componentes retirados do organismo (sangue, urina, tecido, etc.).

## [Revisão](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/revis%C3%A3o)

> re·vi·são
>   (latim revisio, -onis)
>   substantivo feminino
>
> 1. Ato ou efeito de rever.
> 2. Funções de revisor.
> 3. Novo exame, nova leitura.
> 4. Nova análise de uma lei, decreto ou processo, ou da constituição de Estado, para retificar ou anular.
> 5. Exame e emenda de provas tipográficas.
> 6. Lugar ou compartimento privativo do revisor, em tipografia.

---

## Resposta

Pelo menos em Portugal, o termo adequado seria "Revisão". Apesar de muito semelhantes, vou tentar ilustrar a diferença:

- Usar análise:

  > Eu vou ao médico fazer análises ao sangue para ver se está tudo bem.

  Ou seja, analisamos no sentido de obter um resultado.
- Usar revisão:

  > O Gabe disse para eu falar com o bigown para ele fazer uma revisão do código do bfavaretto pois parece não estar a funcionar segundo os requisitos do Sergio.

  Ou seja, revemos no sentido de aprovar ou reprovar algo. Também revemos no sentido de alterar algo. Mais ainda, as análises estão sujeitas a revisões :)

Comment: Apenas por uma questão de rigor: Análise(português) e analyse(francês) vêem ambas do grego análusis.

Comment: Em português do Brasil, creio que Analise também é melhor do que Revisão

Answer (score 6):

A tradução deveria ser **Revisão**.

Até porque na revisão está implícita uma análise:

> Não se pode fazer uma revisão sem fazer uma análise.
>   Mas pode-se fazer uma análise sem se fazer uma revisão.

De forma a melhor exemplificar esta ideia, reformulo os exemplos dados pelo Zuul:

Primeiro vou obter dados sobre o estado da minha saúde. Estes são obtidos através duma análise ao sangue.

> **Análise**
>   Vou ao laboratório fazer análises ao sangue.

Depois vou ao médico para que ele, baseado nas análises feitas, me diga o que está mal.

> **Revisão**
>   Vou ao médico para que ele me diga como agir em conformidade com o resultado das análises.

Isto é o que fazemos aqui no SO.
Analisamos as questões e depois agimos em conformidade. **Fazemos uma Revisão**

Comment: Bom exemplo para ilustrar o significado prático de cada uma das palavras. +1

Answer (score 4):

Os termos são bem semelhantes em significado. Porém ao ler **análise** eu tenho a noção de que é acima de tudo uma tarefa de estudar cada caso em detalhes antes de decidir, enquanto que **revisão** pode ser entendido como passar o olho por algo que já está certo para procurar problemas. Prefiro manter a terminologia atual: **análise**.

Comment: "Peer review" costuma ser traduzido como "revisão por pares" ou "análise por pares"?

Comment: @bfavaretto Costuma ser traduzido por "revisão por pares" ou "revisão de pares" ou ainda "revisão paritária", pelo menos em Portugal http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revis%C3%A3o_por_pares

Comment: @Tivie, é o que eu imaginava. Ponto para "revisão".

Comment: Os termos não são nada semelhantes em significado. Além disso, revisão não pode ser de forma alguma entendida como um "passar de olho", a revisão implica uma análise cuidada.

Comment: @ramaral "revisão implica uma análise" você se contradisse :)

Comment: Não sei porquê. O que eu quero dizer é que você pode fazer uma análise e não fazer uma revisão. Ex.: Você analisa um post mas não toma qualquer decisão se deve manter, eliminar ou melhorar. Neste caso não foi feita qualquer revisão.  Por outro lado, se você tomou uma decisão, agiu de acordo com a análise que fez. A revisão, além da análise, pressupõe uma ação. Que é o que se pede aqui no SO.

Answer (score 0):

Aproveitando o post do @Zuul

Análise:

> Exame minucioso de uma coisa em cada uma das suas partes.

Revisão:

> Ato ou efeito de rever.

Minha sugestão:

## Manter o Analisar

Pois estamos **examinando** posts minuciosamente (assim se espera), conforme mostra o significado de Análise logo acima.

Revisar, como dito pelo @Guilerme Bernal me parece algo superficial, e também me parece algo que fazemos com nosso próprio trabalho, exemplo:

> Vou revisar minha pergunta antes de postá-la para procurar por erros.

No caso, acho estranho dizer que vamos revisar/rever um trabalho que nunca vimos antes.

Dei minha opinião depois de muito pensar, por que a principio esperava que a tradução de Review por lógica deveria ser Revisão, mas achei Análise mais apropriado no final das contas.

Comment: Você opta por Análise porque confunde o significado de Revisão e Análise. A prova está na sua frase: `Vou revisar minha pergunta antes de postá-la para procurar por erros.`, que deveria ser: `Vou analisar minha pergunta antes de postá-la para procurar por erros.`. Só então, se encontrar erros, é que a vai rever para que ela seja postada sem erros. Procurar por erros é uma análise. Corrigir os erros é uma revisão.

Comment: @ramaral `Procurar por erros é uma análise. Corrigir os erros é uma revisão.`. Pois bem, a fila é para procurar por erros, ou seja **fila de análise**, pois se fosse fila de revisão significaria que todas as publicações da fila possuem erros e devem ser consertadas, entretanto isso não é verdade.

Comment: Não me expliquei bem. Você percorre a fila e analisa cada uma das publicações, após essa análise você tem de decidir se mantém, elimina ou melhora. O ato que daí decorre é uma revisão, mesmo que a decisão seja manter.

Comment: @ramaral você usou duas vezes a palavra `analisar` na sua explicação: `Você percorre a fila e **analisa** cada uma das publicações, após essa **análise** você tem de decidir se mantém, elimina ou melhora`. Com base no que você se baseia sua frase que vem depois disso: `O ato que daí decorre é uma revisão, mesmo que a decisão seja manter.` Pois me pareceu que você usou mais naturalmente a palavra `análise` do que `revisão`.

Comment: Quando você clica no botão análise qual é a sua intenção? É apenas analisar as publicações ou é `atuar` em função da análise que fez? Se é `atuar` você está a `rever`. Se você se limitar a olhar para elas e não atuar, você apenas fez uma análise.

Comment: @ramaral Entendi seu ponto, vou refletir e depois volto a expressar minha opinião.