# Mensagem em review/suggested-edits não está traduzida

Tags: bug, internacionalização

Quando se tenta aceder à página para [rever as edições sugeridas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits), com menos de 1K de reputação, a mensagem que aparece é:

> You need at least 1k reputation to review suggested edits.

Quando deveria ser:

> Necessita de, pelo menos, 1K de reputação para poder analisar edições sugeridas

#### Captura de Tela:

[image: Captura de Tela]

Comment: psss... Passa a tua sugestão para uma resposta, assim os utilizadores podem votar a favor ou contra. Mais tarde tens também a oportunidade de marcar a mesma como "Correta" e fechar este tópico quando a tradução estiver aplicada.

Answer (score 3):

Eu sugeria a seguinte tradução:

> Precisa de pelo menos 1k de reputação para rever edições sugeridas.

É um pouco próximo ao que está sugerido na própria pergunta, mas parece-me ficar melhor para o português de Portugal, não sei se resulta para os brasileiros.

---

Relativamente a usar `rever` ou `analisar`, tudo se prende com o consenso que se venha a ter da seguinte discussão:

## [Por que análise, e não revisão?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/904/223)

Comment: Se for "revisão", prefiro "revisar" a "rever"

Comment: Acho melhor evitar pronomes oblíquos (como "você") porque, formalmente, obrigaria a usar sempre a terceira pessoa durante o discurso. Exemplo: 
"Vocês fizeram o seu trabalho de casa?" (correcto formalmente, mas estranho)
"Vocês fizeram o vosso trabalho de casa?" (incorrecto formalmente, mas mais comum)

Comment: @Tivie Sim, concordo, só tinha deixado porque tenho visto por _ai_ o mesmo em uso. Mas por outro lado existem áreas onde não é utilizado... ainda existe algum trabalho a fazer nesse campo até o site estar uniformizado. Contudo, editei a resposta.

Comment: +1 Porque, de facto, prende-se com o consenso

Comment: Comum em Portugal == Estranho no Brasil, @Tivie. E vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

Em nome da uniformização, **todas** as mensagens do tipo:

> You need at least $Rep$ reputation to XXXXX

Foram traduzidas para:

> São necessários pelo menos $rep$ pontos de reputação para XXXXX

Acredito que seja uma maneira menos tendenciosa à PT_PT ou PT_BR. Me corrijam se eu estiver errado.

Comment: Em PT_PT está tudo certo.

Answer (score 1):

Eu sugiro a seguinte tradução:

> Necessita de, pelo menos, 1K de reputação para poder analisar edições sugeridas

Pode, eventualmente, tirar-se a palavra "poder", mas acho que não soa tão bem.

> Necessita de, pelo menos, 1K de reputação para analisar edições sugeridas

---

Pessoalmente, acho que `"Analisar"` é melhor que `"Rever"` só por uma questão de congruência, já que `"Review"` foi traduzido para `"Analisar"` no mesmo ecrã (ve-se na imagem).

Sugiro também tentar evitar-se o uso de pronomes, especialmente pronomes oblíquos (como `"você"`).Isto porque têm cargas de formalidade diferente no PT-pt e no PT-br.
Além disso, obrigaria a usar sempre a terceira pessoa durante o discurso. Exemplo:

- "**Vocês** *fizeram* o **seu** trabalho de casa?" (formalmente correcto, mas estranho)
- "**Vocês** *fizeram* o **vosso** trabalho de casa?" (formalmente incorrecto, mas mais comum)
- "**Vós** *fizesteis* o **vosso** trabalho de casa?" (o mais correcto e o mais estranho)

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar conflitos pt_PT versus pt_BR, sugiro:

**a) Para o caso de "revisão"**

> São necessários pelo menos 1k pontos de reputação para revisar edições sugeridas.

**b) Para o caso de "análise"**

> São necessários pelo menos 1k pontos de reputação para analisar edições sugeridas.

Comment: Revisar não soa lá muito bem em PT-pt