# Tradução na página de Analisar edições sugeridas

Tags: bug, tradução, internacionalização

Após eu ter recebido uma análise e ter editado eu cai na página de Analisar edições sugeridas na aba análise que tinha a seguinte mensagem:

[image: erro tradução analisar traduções sugeridas]

Não sou o melhor para traduzir, mas imagino que posso ficar algo assim:

> Obrigado por sua análise. Você precisa de pelo menos 1k de reputação para rever edições sugeridas.

Depois quando entro novamente não da mais a mensagem de agradecimento e somente o aviso de que preciso de mais de 1000 pontos de reputação para poder rever as edições sugeridas.

Comment: Relacionada: [Mensagem em review/suggested-edits não está traduzida](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/921/mensagem-em-review-suggested-edits-nao-esta-traduzida)

Comment: Correto, não tinha achado.

Answer (score 2):

Minha sugestão é:

> Obrigado pela sua análise. Você precisa de pelo menos 1k de reputação para continuar analisando edições sugeridas.

É claro que podemos trocar `análise` por `revisão` assim que decidirmos isso [**nesse tópico**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/904/3117).

Se decidirmos por revisão:

> Obrigado pela sua revisão. Você precisa de pelo menos 1k de reputação para continuar revisando edições sugeridas.